# Checking all image are loaded using jquery

Tags: jquery, image

I know this is quite a popular question, but I've never found a definitive solution. I've got a dynamically generated page that loads a number of images. Occasionally, due to no fault of our own, there will be a reference to an image that doesn't exist. What's the best way to scan all the images for a broken image link, or rather when is it best to do this because I understand:

```
 $(document).ready(
```

Isn't the most accurate indication that all images have completed loading. If it helps all the images share a class name .myImage.

Thanks.

Update. I tried this but can't get it to work in Chrome:

```
 $(window).load(function(){
     $('.myImage').error(function(){
         //do something
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `.load()`

```
$(window).load(function() {

)}
```

Explanation from [the docs here](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
>   been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
>   associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
>   window object.

an alternative is to update the `<img` tag (if its possible)

```
<img src="yourimage.gif" onload="loaded(this)" />
```

Then you can use the `loaded()` function to keep track of images loaded. [Details on the load event](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/load.html)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out. Must admit I had read conflicting things about the .load event. Don't know if that was problems with older version of jQuery or just my misunderstanding. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @user1001421 working fine for me .... but if you can edit the source - there is a simple alternative (added it to my answer)

Comment: Sorry, crashing and burning a bit. There are a number of reasons why I can't use the onload="loaded(this)" method, so I've been playing with the $(window).load( option and can't get it to work. I've amended my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Found this. Seems to do the trick

[imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded)